# Bouncing sound from a carved concave surface

Tags: acoustics, reflection

Am currently researching to create a large scale sculpture based around a sound mirror-have made several maquettes- using recycled timbers  the timbers would be stacked and screwed with the concave section carved out- scale 3.5 high x 4m wide- I intend the work to be an interactive public sculpture and want people to bounce sound as well as create the opportunity for experimental sounds to be transmitted- excuse my knowledge but I'm keen to know if the recycled carved and sanded concave section will bounce sound- as I have made maquettes but it simply does'nt work on a small scale- if the concave was sanded polished and varnished would that help sound bouncing back?
any advice appreciated

Comment: See https://sciencing.com/types-materials-create-echoes-8788972.html

Comment: A rule of thumb is that features much smaller than a wavelength don't really matter.  The wavelength of sound audible to humans [ranges from 17m to 17mm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sound#Sound_wave_properties_and_characteristics), but the most important pitches are around 17cm — which is 6 inches.  So I'd say you should try to get your sound mirror to be a parabola to within around 1", but sanding and varnishing will have almost no effect.

Answer (score 0):

**The short, non-technical story:** design the sculpture in the shape of a parabola or ellipse, and make the reflector a dense, thick, smooth piece of wood.

Other materials (metal or concrete) may make better reflectors than wood.

---

If you're interested in estimating how effective a particular design is (*a much more difficult challenge,*) read on...

There are two factors that will make your sculpture an effective point-to-point reflector:

- [utilizing focusing geometries](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Acoustic/reflc.html#c2), which it sounds like you may already have employed
- using a material with a high reflection coefficient, $R$

Where:

$$R = \bigl ( \frac{Z_{sculpture} - Z_{air}}{Z_{sculpture} + Z_{air}} \bigr )^2$$

Where $Z$ is the characteristic specific acoustic impedance, a property of materials.

I hope you can see that as the difference between $Z_{sculpture}$ and $Z_{air}$ becomes larger the reflection coefficient becomes larger and larger.

---

The formula for impedance at a specific frequency is

$$Z(f) = i \ 2 \pi  fm \ + \ \ -i \ \frac{\kappa}{2 \pi f}$$

Where $m$ is the mass of material, and $\kappa$ is a measure of it's elasticity, usually [Young's modulus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastic_modulus) or [Bulk modulus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bulk_modulus).

Air obviously has very little mass and is extremely elastic = low value of $Z$.
So for the best reflection we want a sculpture *with a high value of $Z$* to maximize $R$.

Wood is porous and of relatively low density. If you made the reflective part of the sculpture out of denser wood, that will help (increase $m$) or you can [increase the thickness of the reflective part as well](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/387546/acoustic-amplitude-transmission-through-multi-layer-medium/387707?noredirect=1#comment870585_387707) (increase $L$ - *see equation in linked post*) which will tend to improve the reflection of higher frequency energy like voices.

Comment: I do not think the asker is equipped to understand your formulas, nor to make use of them. (Where is $L$ in your formulas?)

Comment: Perhaps your right - if I'm lucky it's useful, but perhaps not.  I don't really think it's my role to filter, just to provide a solid answer.  I like to give people the benefit of the doubt.  The $L$.  Ah, that's a bit sloppy of me - it's part of an equation in the linked post.

Comment: I think a summary for folks like myself (and the OP) would be:  Harder surfaces reflect better, and wood may be too soft to make a good reflector.

Comment: Wood is definitely capable of reflecting sound.  I would be more worried about how well supported the wood is; you don't want it being too resonant and thus inefficient at reflecting.